# Does using the extension method ToList<T>() waste resources?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have a question about LINQ, `IEnumerable<>`, and `List<>`.

When I have a `List<T>` and want to filter or search it, I use LINQ like this:

```
var psec = from p in MyListOfSomeObjects
           where ((p.Tipo == tipo) || (p.Tipo == null))
           select p;
```

But in one particular case, I need an actual `List<T>`, instead of an `IEnumerable<T>` as returned by the LINQ query.

I could use `psec.ToList<T>()` to get my `List<T>`, but my question is:

Does the method `ToList<T>()` waste time or computer resources? Does it do some iteration or loop across the `IEnumerable<T>` to build a `List<T>`?

Answer (score 5):

> Do the method Tolist<>() waste time or computer resources?

It depends.  If you *need* a list, then it's likely not a waste.  It does use time and resources to build the list.

> Do it some iteration or loop across the IEnumerable psec to build a List<> ?

Yes.  It iterates through the enumerable and builds the list from the items within it.

In general, if your goal is just to enumerate through the results (ie: use in a `foreach` loop), there's no need to convert to a `List<T>` via `ToList()`, and doing so is just wasteful.

Comment: If you use it as a single LINQ statement, do you know if the ToList is optmized to any degree?

Comment: @James No - it doesn't matter whether it's done in one "statement" or not.  The compiler treats it the same way, and it's just a method call.  `ToList()` just (effectively) returns `new List<T>(sourceEnumerable)`

Comment: @James its really exactly the same as if you do: `List<YourType> newList = new List<YourType>(psec);`